# Dynamic task tree without using retry

Tags: celery

[image]

I want to make task tree as on the attached picture.

If I knew from the start what N is, I could just use this code:

> >>> chain(group(chain(A.s(), group(a.s() for x in xrange(3)), B.s()), chain(C.s(), D.s())), E.s())()

Which works ok for static N = 3. (Hmm... it doesn't really  work - for some reason subtask E is not executed, I don't know why)

Basically I do some calculations in 'A' task and want to create 'a' task N times, where N depends on those calculations.

Then I want to call 'B' task which gathers all results from 'a' tasks.

Finally when 'B' and 'D' are done I want to run 'E'.

I can do what I want to achieve if I use retry (you can create any dependency tree if using retry), which I don't want to since it's not very elegant.

> >>> group(A.s(), chain(C.s(), D.s()))

```
@app.task()
def A(*args):
    # calculations
    chord(a.s() for i in xrange(N))(B.s())

@app.task()
def B(*args):
    # calculations
    E.delay()

@app.task(bind=True)
def E(*args):
    try:
        if D not ready then:
            raise Exception()
    except Exception as e:
        self.retry(countdown=60, exc=e)
```

So the question is, how to do it without retry?

Comment: Instead of retry, can't you just D.get() ? Still not a good solution but something better

Comment: D.get() in E wouldn't be that bad if what I drew was the whole process. In fact it is just a part of a bigger graph. D.get() would waste 1 worker when waiting which I think isn't better than retry at all.